# Function from a higher order applied to an array

Tags: c++, class, higher-order-functions, pointer-to-member

I have a vector of a specific class type;

```
vector<Song> database;
```

and

```
class Song
{
public:
    string getName() const;
    string getSinger() const;
    unsigned int getLength();
    unsigned short getYear() const;

private:
    char singer[51];
    char name[51];
    unsigned int length;
    unsigned short year;
};
```

Note that the vector is not within the Song class. It's in another class. In that other class I have created a function from a higher order. One of the parameters of that function is a getter from the Song class:

```
void order(string, int, Song*, unsigned int (Song::*get)(), bool(*compare)(unsigned int, unsigned int));
```

However, when I make a call like this:

```
database[a].(obj->*get())
```

I understand that when I have to deal with functions from other classes, I have to give a reference to an object of that class, and give a reference to the function from that class as well. My question is whether I can pass a function reference that will automatically detect the object that I am working with?

**EDIT**

```
void Interface::order(string command, int findLength,
    Song* obj, unsigned int (Song::*get)(), bool(*compare)(unsigned int first, unsigned int second))
{
    for (unsigned int a = 0; a < database.size(); a++)
    {
        if (compare(database[a].(obj->*get)(), stoi(command)))
        {
            cout << "Deleting found match...\n";
            database.erase(database.begin() + a);
        }
    }
}
```

I get an error at `database[a].(obj->*get)()`
The error there is that the compiler expected a member name. However, I want to give a function that is not dependend on the object that i have passed. In other words, I'm asking if there is a type of construction which allows me to pass one function as a parameter here, and that function will automatically call each object [from the vector of songs] and its respective getter method.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understood your question, but I believe [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) does what you want.

Comment: you mean so that you can use `this` inside your `Song::get`?

Comment: Isn't `database[a]` a `Song`? Why not just do `database[a].getLength()`?

Comment: ... and your `order` function gets a `Song*` too

Comment: The order function is within a class named Interface. In that class I have a vector of songs. I want to have a function which will be able to call one specific getter function (depending on the case) for each object of the vector..

Comment: Ah, is your question is "Given a `Song` object and a `Song::*`, how do I call that function?"

Comment: @Mackiavelli It still isn't clear why `order` takes a `Song* obj`. Could you explain, without code, how a song from the `database`, say `database[0]` and the `Song* obj` are supposed to interact in `order`?

Comment: @Pradhan I was using the advice you gave me yesterday lol. I figured out that it wouldn't work here, but I had already written it this way. I suppose that now I only have to pass the &A::*get() function?

Comment: @Mackiavelli Yeah that's right.

Comment: @Pradhan How am I supposed to call te compare function after that? I get an error about apparent call pointer to function???
this->*comparator((database[a].*get)(), stoi(command))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about the `->*` syntax for accessing member functions through a member function pointer: that is the syntax when you have a pointer to the object.

There is another syntax for accessing a member function through a member object:

```
(database[a].*get)()
```

This would call a member function pointed to by `get` on a `Song` object at `database[a]`.